# PUT request in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write a simple `PUT` request method in Spring MVC. I got the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT) 
public @ResponseBody User updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, 
                                     String name, 
                                     String email) {
        User user = repository.findOne(id);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        repository.save(user);
        return user; 
}
```

Which is obviously wrong, because it returns the following:

```
User{id=1, name='null', email='null'}
```

I also tried with `@RequestBody` annotation, but that also did not help. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You did not tell spring how to bind the `name` and `email` parameters from the request. For example, by adding a `@RequestParam`:

```
public @ResponseBody User updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, 
                                     @RequestParam String name, 
                                     @RequestParam String email) { ... }
```

`name` and `email` parameters will be populated from the query strings in the request. For instance, if you fire a request to `/users/1?name=Josh&email=jb@ex.com`, you will get this response:

```
User{id=1, name='Josh', email='jb@ex.com'}
```

In order to gain more insight about defining handler methods, check out the spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/index.html#mvc-ann-methods).

Answer (score 19):

You can receive `name` and `email` whith the `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT) 
public @ResponseBody User updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, 
                                     @RequestBody User user) {}
```

This is a better practice when it comes to REST applications, as your URL becomes more clean and rest-style. 
You can even put a @Valid annotation on the `User` and validate its properties.

On your postman client, you send the `User` as a JSON, on the body of your request, not on the URL. Don't forget that your `User` class should have the same fields of your sent JSON object.

See here:
[image]

Comment: I did that, it didn't work for me for some reason, returned weird parsing problems when I was doing the queries with Postman. I settled for `@RequestPart` instead.

Comment: @sosek I edited my answer and added how you should do in postman.