# why i am getting zero in pwaSourceId but i am passing 13 form url also I am printing at controller and also at dao stil its zero there also?

Tags: java, spring, rest

This is my Dao.java class

```
public int updatePwaSourceDetails(PwaSourceDetails pwa){System.out.println("pwa.getPwaSourceID()"); //out is zero here 
    String query="update pwa_source set name='"+pwa.getName()+"',is_deleted='"+pwa.getIsDeleted()+"',created_by='"+pwa.getCreatedBy()+"',created_time='"+pwa.getCreatedTime()+"',modified_by='"+pwa.getModifiedBy()+"',modified_time='"+pwa.getModifiedTime()+"'  where pwa_source_id="+pwa.getPwaSourceID()+"";  
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    }
```

this is my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updateEmployeee(@ModelAttribute("PwaSourceDetails") PwaSourceDetails pwa1)
{
System.out.println("pwa1.getPwaSourceID()"); //out is zero here also  
pwaSourceDetailsService.updatePwaSourceDetails(pwa1);
}
```

this is the url

http://localhost:7080/vitality-web/boardsource/update?pwaSourceId=13&name=Agile&isDeleted=0&createdBy=1&createdTime=2017-08-02%2005:00:00&modifiedBy=1&modifiedTime=2017-08-02%2005:00:00

In database

```
pwaSourceId-int
name-varchar
isDeleted-int
createdBy-int
createdTime-Timestamp
modifiedBy-int
modifiedTime-Timestamp
```

this is the error I am getting

```
root cause

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback;
bad SQL grammar [update pwa_source set name='nitish',is_deleted=0,created_by=1,created_time=,modified_by=1,modified_time=  where pwa_source_id=0];
nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'modified_by=1,modified_time=  where pwasourceid=0' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send parameters in url, like in GET request, but your controller expect, that you send model in the body of request. You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35880456/8319308

Comment: I have used it with get also still same result

Answer (score 0):

you need a @RequestParam here, and you are sending pwaSourceId as single number so your controller method should be like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updateEmployeee(@RequestParam("PwaSourceDetails") long pwa1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `@ModelAttribute("PwaSourceDetails")` to  `@RequestBody` annotation and send data in JSON like below

```
{
     "pwaSourceId": "13",
     "name": "Agile",
     "isDeleted": "0",
     "createdBy": "1",
     "createdTime": "2017-08-02%2005:00:00",
     "modifiedBy": "1",
     "modifiedTime": "2017-08-02%2005:00:00"
}
```