# Does @RequestParameter only work with GetMapping and PostMapping?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have these mappings:

```
@GetMapping("rparam")
public void get(@RequestParam("test") String test) {
    System.out.println(test);
}

@PostMapping("rparam")
public void post(@RequestParam("test") String test) {
    System.out.println(test);
}

@PatchMapping("rparam")
public void patch(@RequestParam("test") String test) {
    System.out.println(test);
}

@DeleteMapping("rparam")
public void delete(@RequestParam("test") String test) {
    System.out.println(test);
}

@PutMapping("rparam")
public void put(@RequestParam("test") String test) {
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

And apart from the GetMapping and PostMapping methods all the other ones fail with 400 Bad request because they can't find the test parameter.

edit: 
How the requests are made (the post one works):

(stringifying the data and adding a contentType:application/json doesn't help either)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/my-controller/rparam",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        test: "super test"
    },
    headers: {
        "X-XSRF-TOKEN": cookie
    }
}).done(function() {
    console.log("super cool")
});
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/my-controller/rparam",
    method: "PUT",
    data: {
        test: "super test"
    },
    headers: {
        "X-XSRF-TOKEN": cookie
    }
}).done(function() {
    console.log("super cool")
});
```

edit: I just noticed that when I don't stringify the data and set a contentType it's sent as form data. And sending data via a form only supports post and get so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: how do you access them ? do you access them like this : localhost:<port>/rparam?test=test  ?

Comment: The methods are the same so probably the problem is not in that code :) its either how you access them or how your servlet is made

Comment: you need to add some code where you actually access these endpoints

Comment: I added how the requests are made

Comment: Is it possible to use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam` for PATCH, PUT and DELETE requests ?

Comment: Then I'd have to create a wrapper for every value that's not part of an object. Or I'd have to create a class just so that it can include that one value plus the existing class that's also part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving some default value by changing your method:

```
public void delete(@RequestParam(value = "test" , defaultValue = "default") String test)
```

Answer (score 0):

[@RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) can work with with all kind of [@RequestMapping](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping):

- @GetMapping
- @PostMapping
- @PutMapping
- @DeleteMapping
- @PatchMapping

However, about semantics, PATCH, PUT and DELETE are supposed to accept the body of the request, and then update / store / remove the object on the resource identified by the URI.

So, I recommand using `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`.

You can take a look at [this very similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35878351/9640261)